# Sort working opposite

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I have a mongo collection:

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351"),
  "cust_id" : "abc123",
  "ord_date" : ISODate("2012-10-03T18:30:00Z"),
  "status" : "A",
  "price" : 25,
  "items" : [{
      "sku" : "ggg",
      "qty" : 7,
      "price" : 2.5
    }, {
      "sku" : "ppp",
      "qty" : 5,
      "price" : 2.5
    }]
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51fa1c318188d305fcbf9f9b"),
  "cust_id" : "abc123",
  "ord_date" : ISODate("2012-10-03T18:30:00Z"),
  "status" : "A",
  "price" : 27,
  "items" : [{
      "sku" : "ggg",
      "qty" : 7,
      "price" : 2.5
    }, {
      "sku" : "ppp",
      "qty" : 5,
      "price" : 2.5
    }]
}
```

When I am giving the aggregate query for sorting in ascending order:

```
 db.orders.aggregate([{
     "$unwind": "$items"
 }, {
     "$sort": {
         "price": -1
     }
 }, {
     "$match": {}
 }, {
     "$group": {
         "price": {
             "$first": "$price"
         },
         "items": {
             "$push": {
                 "sku": "$items.sku"
             }
         },
         "_id": "$_id"
     }
 }, {
     "$project": {
         "_id": 0,
         "price": 1,
         "items": 1
     }
 }])
```

I get result:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "price": 25,
        "items": [{
            "sku": "ggg"
        }, {
            "sku": "ppp"
        }]
    }, {
        "price": 27,
        "items": [{
            "sku": "ggg"
        }, {
            "sku": "ppp"
        }]
    }]
}
```

i.e it is sorting in ascending order and vice versa.

Comment: Do the `sort` after `project`

Comment: @sza it works, but when I am doing natural sorting it doesn't work.[ { "$unwind" : "$items"} , { "$match" : { }} , { "$group" : { "price" : { "$first" : "$price"} , "items" : { "$push" : { "sku" : "$items.sku"}} , "_id" : "$_id"}} , { "$project" : { "_id" : 0 , "price" : 1 , "items" : 1}} , { "$sort" : { "$natural" : 1}}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `$sort` after `$group`, since the previous sort will be lost after grouping.

```
 db.orders.aggregate([{
     "$unwind": "$items"
 }, {
     "$match": {}
 }, {
     "$group": {
         "price": {
             "$first": "$price"
         },
         "items": {
             "$push": {
                 "sku": "$items.sku"
             }
         },
         "_id": "$_id"
     }
 }, {
     "$sort": {
         "price": -1
     }
 }, {
     "$project": {
         "_id": 0,
         "price": 1,
         "items": 1
     }
 }])
```

For `$natural` operator, this is the quoted from the [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/natural/).

> The $natural operator uses the following syntax to return documents **in
>   the order they exist on disk**

Long story short, that means the order you see is not necessarily consistent with the order it store in DB.

Comment: I use the syntax as mentioned but I am getting error:"command failed [aggregate]: { "serverUsed" : "/10.170.8.112:27017" , "errmsg" : "exception: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'." , "code" : 16410 , "ok" : 0.0}",

Comment: Updated. sort should come after $group but before $project

Comment: the same error I get when I try to use {$match:{$where:"price>5"}}

Comment: @PhalguniMukherjee I don't think $match can work with $where, try `{$match : { price: { $gt : 5}}}`